# Least upper bound where rationals intersect a set

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that $\Bbb{Q}$ has no least upper bound, so this is where I'm struggling:

Where $\Bbb{Q}$ intersects with the set (1,pi], how can there be a least upper bound if $\Bbb{Q}$ doesn't have one?  I know it can't be pi, since it's irrational.

Comment: note the difference of least upper bound and least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q} \cap (1,\pi]$ does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$, as you've suggested.

Note that "$\mathbb{Q}$ does not have a least upper bound" is not the correct statement. Indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ does not have a least upper bound either. Instead, $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have the "least upper bound property", which is to say that there exist bounded subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ which have no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That's what I thought!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's right, there is no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.  For any upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$, such as 3.2, there is a lower upper bound.  That's one of the uses of irrational numbers.